'Print/merge documents' action not appearing for searchkit membership searches
I'm running a somewhat complicated subscription management system using memberships for subscriptions. We have multiple membership types and membership organisations. It is likely that subscribers will have two or more subscriptions with different membership organisations.
I need to print an envelope for each membership regularly. I'm using smart groups to group memberships that need to be printed together (e.g. all envelopes from the same state need to be grouped). When I set up a searchkit/formbuilder combo to display the memberships, the action 'print/merge document' doesn't appear in the actions drop down menu.
I have tried using a searchkit contacts search as a workaround but this was unsuitable because, where there are multiple memberships for a contact, the print/merge document skips some of the memberships because they belong to the same contact.
Another workaround I've tried is the "find memberships" option. This failed because when separating by smart groups, the search brings up all memberships of a contact with any one membership in that smart group (this does not occur in searchkit/formbuilder combos). If I don't use smart groups, it gets too messy to handle the variety of segmentations needed.

I managed to resolve this issue by using the Search Action Designer extension. It took a lot of trial and error because I needed to set up lots of 'get' actions to get the correct data for the necessary tokens required as part of the merge document action, but works great once set up.
